# How do you get a cell's content in an Excel spreadsheet using Java? Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm creating a Java application that I need it to read specific cells, the cells on the document will contain Strings and some Integers. Can you please assist, I found this sample code below, but now I'm stuck. I need to persist the data on the spreadsheet to the database. Thank You

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");
    //InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");

    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
```

Comment: A quick search get me this simple yet useful blog http://sanjaal.com/java/100/java-file/reading-excel-file-using-java-and-apache-poi/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your code to a working sample:

```
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inp);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
        System.out.println("string: " + cell.getStringCellValue());
    }
    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
        System.out.println("numeric: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }
    System.out.println("any: " + cell.toString());
```

I hope it helps!